# Changing the checkbox square box from square to rounded with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, backend, cornerradius

I have successfully created the rounded corner for the checkbox, right now I have issues connecting the control template with other checkboxes, is there anyway to connect the control template to the checkbox generated from the back end?

the first part is the control template modified to change the square box to rounded box

the second part is the checkbox generated from backend and added to the front end

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="15" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                        <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

----------------------------------------------

 private void GenerateCheckbox()
        {
            CheckBox checkBoxTest = new CheckBox();
            checkBoxTest.Content = "Test";
            grid.Children.Add(checkBoxTest);
        }
```

[image: weird]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the `ControlTemplate` within your `Resources`

```
checkBoxTest.Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["CheckBoxTemplate1"]
```

This assumes this code is written within the code-behind of the `Window` where the resource is defined. If not, then you will need to do the lookup on an element where the resource is in scope. You can also do a lookup on your app-wide resources defined within `Application`.

Comment: um im lost now, the first method cant work while the second method kinda weird, by weird, u can see the new screenshot i share above, the checkbox generated become a single line

Comment: I have updated my answer as I have clearly misunderstood what resource you wanted to apply. I'd suggest only posting the relevant code.